# I can't navigate to my user folder at the command prompt in Windows 10

Tags: command-prompt, windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10.  When I open the command prompt, it opens in my user folder,  C:\Users\tmadden.  If I navigate somewhere else, I can't return to my user folder.  I get "The system cannot find the path specified.

The same error happens when I run command prompt as an administrator. 
Please let me know how to navigate to my user folder again.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: you have 3 ds in the directory name.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  How embarrassing!.  I misspelled my own name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your user name is `tmaddden` but you are trying to go through `tmadden`.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I can't believe I didn't notice that.